# Bash scripting: run a shell command from inside a script with variable inside quotes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, mysql

I need to load a db into a mysql server and the following command works from the shell:
**From shell**

```
mysql -h "172.17.0.2" -u "root"  -p"mypasswd" -Bse "create database mydb;"
```

But not from the script, in which the ip and the password are variables passed as arguments:

**The script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
sqlname=$1
sqlpass=$2
sqlip=$3
...  
set -x
echo "Creating the database..."
mysql -h $sqlip -u "root" -p$sqlpass -Bse "create database mydb;"
```

**The result of the script:**

```
./myscript.sh mysql1 mypasswd 172.17.0.2
```

> Creating the database...
>   + mysql -h 172.17.0.2 -u root -pmypasswd -Bse 'create database mydb;'
>    ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   '172.17.0.2' (111)

-- begin edit
Same result for the variables inside double quotes:

```
#!/bin/bash  
...  
mysql -h "$sqlip" -u root -p"$sqlpass" -Bse "create database mydb;"
```

> + echo 'Creating the database...'   Creating the database...
>   + mysql -h 172.17.0.2 -u root -pmypasswd -Bse 'create database mydb;'   ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   '172.17.0.2' (111)

-- end edit

Double quotes and singles quotes with variables inside the script confuse me.

I am missing something obvious here about using variables inside and with quotes.

Any hint?

Comment: Done. I am using a very simple password for testing, as simple as "mypasswd"

Answer (score 1):

The use of quotes is to stop the shell interpreting certain punctuation characters, such as space (parameter separator), `>` (output redirection), `*` (wild-card in file mask), etc.

Single quotes stop all interpretation of the quoted text, while double quotes allow `$` expansion (and some others). The command inside a script is no different from that typed to an interactive prompt.

The IP address has no shell-specific characters, nor has `root`, so they do not need to be quoted. If your password has shell-specific characters, such as a space, it will need to be quoted, and because it requires `$` expansion they need to be double quotes. The `-Bse` parameter has both space and `;`, so it needs quoting, but either will do, since there is no `$` expansion.

The variables you are expanding `$sqlip` and `$sqlpass` need to be defined within the subshell which executes the script, so they need to be set in the subshell or set as `export` in the calling shell.

Comment: Hi @afh. In the script I use the shebang that will run the script in a subshell (edited the question). Is that what yo meant?

Comment: @AJN - No. Scripts _always_ run in a subshell, unless invoked with the `source` / `.` command.

Comment: Where is `172.17.0.2`? Is it the same machine as you're running on? Is it on your intranet?

Comment: It is a container, and there is no issue of connectivity. I tested the  command (mentioned in the beginning of the question) from the host console and it works.

Comment: Searching for "sql error 2003 HY000 111" gives a lot of solutions, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1420862/5164855) and the following answer. But your command-line and script commands appear to be the same, so I don't see how this can vary in the script, unless you have unexported [configuration variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/setting-environment-variables.html), such as `MYSQL_TCP_PORT`.

Answer (score 1):

It’s possible that there are some characters in the password variable which are treated specially by the shell.

As a rule, it’s best practice to **always quote shell variables** to avoid unwanted side effects such as token splitting and wildcard expansion. See [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary) from Unix and Linux Stack Exchange.

```
mysql -h "$sqlip" -u root -p"$sqlpass" -Bse "create database mydb;"
```

Comment: Inside the script, I wrapped the variables in double quotes, but gives the same result (Look at the edited question).